# To save macro generated excel file as .CSH

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on macro , In this macro I generate output data in output sheet and then I have to save that output sheet as .CSH at desired location.

I am using below mentioned code , it saves the file with .CSH but when I open that .CSH file with notepad it shows garbage data (random characters).

Is it possible to save file as .CSH using excel vba ? if yes please suggest how can i do that where file will not show data as garbage values ?

```vb
    Dim wb As Workbook, InitFileName As String, fileSaveName As String
    InitFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "OUTPUTFILE"
    Sheets(Array("OUTPUT")).Copy
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename_ 
    (InitialFileName:=InitFileName,filefilter:="Excel files , *.csh")
    With wb
    If fileSaveName <> "False" Then
        .SaveAs fileSaveName
        .Close
    Else
        .Close False
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
```

[Excel file and .csh file opened in notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LCDj.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UodQ.jpg)

I was expecting it will open and show data same as excel

Comment: Whatever `.csh` is, it's not an Excel file. There's no such option in Excel. Did you confuse it with CSV text files?

Comment: Excel files are ZIP packages containing XML files. They aren't text files and can't be read using text editors. There are libraries that can read Excel files in all languages, eg ExcelDataReader in .NET, openpyxl and Pandas in Python

Comment: You are saving the file in Excel-format. Therefore notepad will show you the binary Excel-file. Do you probably mean you want to save as csv (not csh)? Then you will have to specify `fileformat` with `saveas` (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)

Comment: Notepad converts the characters it saves in ANSI Latin encoding UTF-8 by default. To ensure that you are reading the unconverted contents of the file use something like Textpad  ...   https://www.textpad.com/home

Comment: A CSH file is a script that can be run with the Unix C shell (or a C shell variant like tcsh). It contains instructions written in a command language similar to the C/C++ programming language. Users can execute the commands a CSH file contains by calling the file with the C shell (csh). (Google)

Comment: No guys I am not confusing it with CSV , CSH is a shell script file as mentioned by user10186832 , I am still finding the solution tho'

Comment: Try saving it as a TXT file, but with the file suffix of CSH. `.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName, FileFormat:= xlTextWindows`

Comment: Why do you need to save data as shell script?

Comment: Found the answer                                                                                                    .SaveAs fileName:=Path1 & "\OUTPUT FILE" + Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDDhhmm") & ".CSH", FileFormat:=xlTextWindows, CreateBackup:=False